# Set up all dependencies in one gradle file?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

## What I have

I have two different modules in my android project:

- app: This is the main app android module, where is located almost all the code of the app.
- core: This is another module where I would like to specify all the base code that will be used in the app module, like BaseFragment, BaseViewModel, or interfaces that I would like to implement in the app module.

In the core `build.gradle` file, I have all of these dependencies:

```
    //Moshi
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$moshi_version"
    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$moshi_converter_version"
    //okhttp
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp3_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp_loggin_interceptor"
    //Koin
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:$koin_version"
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:$koin_viewmodel_version"
```

All of these dependencies I would like not to be declared also in the app `build.gradle` file.

I am reading some blogs and the [Gradle official documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html#declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects) but I am not able to successfully achieve this.

## What I want

I want to "inherit" all the dependencies just from the core module gradle file

The structure of the project should be something like this:

```
core
|_build.gradle (common dependencies)
|_app
  |_build.gradle (just specific dependencies)
```

## What I have tried

I have read that this is possible implementing the core project as follows (in the app build.gradle file):

```
dependencies {
  implementation project (":core")
  ......
}
```

But I have some classes in the app module that uses core classes` that could not find. For example:

```
import com.example.core.presentation.base.BaseViewModel
```

The error says that could not resolve the reference like it not exists.

Some ideas?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `implementation project (":core")` should be in your app modules build.gradle not the core modules (as you say in your question)

Comment: Oh! sorry, I just wanted to say app module! @Blundell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your GitHub :-)

I think this is the example you are trying

https://github.com/smoralb/BaseApplication/tree/feature/core?

What you describe in your question should work, so I took a look.

The problem is in your core modules `build.gradle` line 1

(https://github.com/smoralb/BaseApplication/blob/feature/core/core/build.gradle#L1)

You have this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

When you should have this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

then using

```
implementation project (":core")
```

inside your app module, will give you access to the classes from `core` in `app`.

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize this.  I have tried but it seems that has a problem with the dependencies, it says that it has missing or mixing dependencies.

The changed I made were:
1. Move all dependencies to the core `build.gradle` file.
2. Modify `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` in the core `build.gradle` file
3. Add implementation of the core module in the app `build.gradle` file and delete the rest of the dependencies.
`dependencies {
    implementation project (':core')
}
`

Comment: This is the core file https://github.com/smoralb/BaseApplication/blob/feature/core/core/build.gradle And this the app file https://github.com/smoralb/BaseApplication/blob/feature/core/app/build.gradle

Comment: If you want to make the dependencies you declared in core available in app, you need to change their prefix from `implementation` to `api` (in the core file)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to achieve this is with a convention plugin. Don't let the plugin part scare you too much, it's a bit of setup but not that complex.

You get 3 options there:

1. put the plugins in a buildSrc dir and have gradle pick it up automatically
2. put the plugin in a specific module and include the build (composite build)
3. put the plugin in a specific module, release it and load it as a binary dependency plugin.

more info can be found here:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html

alternatively, if you just want to maintain the versions in 1 place but don't mind putting the dependencies in both build gradle files a plaform might be even easier: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html

Comment: Thanks! I am gonna take a look at this.